# Position div under div with unknown height

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="content">
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>sample text</p>
</div>

<div class="nav-bar">
nav links
</div>
```

I want the "nav-bar" div to be positioned on the right under the heading. The heading is an unknown height as it may overflow onto the other line and the paragraph can be any height.

Without altering the HTML, is this possible with CSS or do you have to use JavaScript? I know this can be done with position:absolute if the heading was a known height but not if it can be any height.

Comment: I know you said you can't alter the HTML, but think for a second about what you're asking. If the `nav-bar` is supposed to be right below the `heading`, then the markup should reflect that. It's going to make this task 100x easier.

Comment: what do you mean positioned tot he right, under the heading. heading as in the `<h1>` tag? you can just do `text-align: right` the `nag-bar` div will automatically go under the `content` div. please give an example so we can understand better

Comment: @DaveLunny The nav bar isn't part of the article though so it wouldn't be semantically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place them both inside a container and then align them as you wish.
It also depends if `content`is 100% wide or not.

Comment: I need more of a hint than that about how to align them.

Answer (score 0):

Without altering the HTML: https://jsfiddle.net/53fa57ye/1/

This is with the expectation that there will not be multiple paragraph elements under the heading.

```
.nav-bar {
  float: right;
}

h1 + p {
  position: absolute;
}
```

The problem in this method is, that the paragraph wont have any actual height, so if you have content below it, there will be problems.

If you really can't affect the heading & p HTML, I'd go with a bit of CSS & JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/53fa57ye/4/

Comment: Thanks for the code! So if something is below it the only possibility is to use JavaScript?